# TextViews not moving to Start position in constraint layout

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

For some reason the `TextViews` in my `ConstraintLayout` won't move at all and are stuck in the middle. How can I move them to the Left/Start position? I tried the following but neither of these worked. Any ideas on what else to use?

- `android:gravity="start"`
- `app:flow_horizontalBias="0.0"`

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutB"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                    <!--Constraint 1-->
                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutBTitle"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/ibB1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvB1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ibB1"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>
                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <!--Constraint 2-->
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutBContent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivB2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvB2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        app:flow_horizontalBias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivB2"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivB2"
                        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvB3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvB4"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivB2"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivB2"
                        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivB4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivB2"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivB2"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivB2"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvB4"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvB4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivB4"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvB3"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivB4"
                        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can You add whole layout?

Comment: @iknow Sorry, forgot about that. I have added it now.

Comment: This textViews have to be equally expanded vertically or You just want to have them on the heights as now?

Comment: @iknow I want my text on the left, not in the middle

Comment: Like [this?](https://i.imgur.com/t3KWCYJ.png)

Comment: @iknow Yes, exactly like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is, I just set bias to `0.0`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--Constraint 1-->
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutBTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibB1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvB1"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ibB1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <!--Constraint 2-->
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutBContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivB2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvB2"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivB2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivB2"
                tools:text="2a" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvB3"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvB4"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivB2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivB2"
                tools:text="2b" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivB4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivB2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivB2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivB2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvB4"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvB4"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivB4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvB3"
                tools:text="2c" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Result:

[image]

---

*But I think in Your layout You have added too many constraints. You don't have to set the constraint to the end of the card view for every textView. It will automatically go to start if You just add one.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get something like that, copy the code below.

[image]

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

The key to put the textView to the left is expand the textview to match the constraint.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutB"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <!--Constraint 1-->
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutBTitle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibB1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvB1"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="tvB1"
                app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ibB1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <!--Constraint 2-->
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutBContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivB2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvB2"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="tvb2"
                app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivB2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivB2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivB2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvB3"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="tvb3"
                app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvB4"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivB2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivB4" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivB4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivB2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivB2"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvB4"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="tvb4"
                app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivB4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvB3" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I want my text on the left, not in the middle

Comment: Now if it is the result you want?